# Should I worry about InteropServices.COMException thrown when "Just My Code" is disabled (C#)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, comexception

I have a C# project that references a third party dll. When "Just My Code" is enabled in VS, everything works great and debugger doesn't stop on any exception. If I disable "Just My Code", a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException is thrown from the referenced dll saying:

> HResult=0x8007007E   Message=Retrieving the COM class factory for
> component with CLSID {xxx-xxx-xxx} failed due
> to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be
> found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

However, if I click continues in the debugger, the program goes on and continues normally as if nothing had happened. I have no idea what's causing this... And it seems that a try{}catch() around that line of code doesn't change anything.

Is there a risk that this error impact my software in production if I realease it as is ? Or is the fact that the program continues without error means the exception is already handled in the dll? I feel there is something I don't get here but not sure what... Any clue/explantation about what could be causing this is also most welcome.

Comment: Based on my research, if "Just My Code" is enabled in vs, the debugger displays and steps into user code ("My Code") only, ignoring system code and other code that is optimized or that does not have debugging symbols. Therefore, If your app only uses your code, you don't worry about the problem. But if you used system dll, I think it is necessary for you to check your code to solve the exception.